# Calling static functions that don't exist

Tags: actionscript-3

I'd like to have a class that will resolve calls to static functions that don't exist.

If you have an object that subclasses the Proxy class, you can override the callProperty() method to catch calls to functions, as properties of that object, that don't exist.

How can this be done with static function calls in a class? It cannot be done by making the overridden callProperty() method static. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think there is any way to do what you are asking.  Static functions have to exist and be called static so the compiler knows that they are there.  I can't see any way around that.  Is there any way to do what you want without it being static? Maybe if you described more about what you are trying to achieve I might be able to be more of a help.

Comment: I had thought that might be the case. I have other ways to achieve the behaviour I'm after. I had just thought the Proxy class (or something similar) might offer a standardized way to accomplish this. I'm going to leave the question open for now, because I'm not convinced there's not any combination of symbols that'll allow for this (perhaps dynamic classes are different? Doubtful, but something I'm now going to investigate). Thanks for the thought.

Comment: yeah if you every find a way I would be interested to hear about it.  I can see being able to marshal a method like this, but I think the static part is going to be your problem.  But please let me know when you get a conclusion.